# For-in with a hard-coded array

Tags: javascript

Rookie JS question here:

```
for( var p in ['nodeName', 'nodeType', 'tagName', 'localName'] ) {
    console.log( p + '=' + all[i][p] + '\n' );
}
```

I expected to see something like

```
nodeName=DIV
```

Instead, I get

```
0=undefined
```

Am I forced to assign the array to a variable, so that I can index into it?  Is there a way to use this syntax in the for-in and retrieve the string from the array?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the `i` in `all[i][p]`?

Comment: From a debugging and readability standpoint making the array a variable is preferable to an anonymous array.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. Yeah, I'm iterating over the DOM, so `all=document.getElementsByTagName("*")`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `for..in` for an array is **almost always wrong**. It iterates over object properties, not over values -s so in your case it yields you 0, 1, 2 and 3. It gets **even worse** if you decide to extend `Array.prototype` with custom methods (which, unlike extending `Object.prototype` is not a big no-go). Their names will also be iterated over when using `for..in`.

The proper way to do what you want is this:

```
var foo = [...];
for(var i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
    // use foo[i]
}
```

or this (in modern browsers or with the function being shim'd):

```
[...].forEach(function(value) {
    // use value
});
```

Comment: Or you could use Array.forEach

Comment: Or even, as of ECMA5, `[].forEach(function(val, key) {...`

Comment: Thanks. For the sake of others, here is what I ended up with:
    `['nodeName', 'nodeType', 'tagName', 'localName'].forEach(function(p) {
        str += p + '=' + all[i][p] + '\n';
    });`
Sorry about the formatting in the comment section.

Comment: at least you didn't post it as an answer :p